# Running Javascript in Android WebView - onPageFinished Loop

Tags: javascript, android, json, webview

I am having a bit of trouble getting my application to correctly run some JS on a page using the onPageFinished method.

The code below is contained within a class I've created that extends AsyncTask to fetch and parse a JSON file held elsewhere.

I am able to fetch the JSON file correctly, parse the data and the url for the WebView is obtained and set. Everything works loads as it should until I attempt to run some JS with the onPageFinished method.

```
        //onPostExecute method runs when the doInBackground method is completed
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        //Casting as WebView as findViewById doesnt explicity return a value type.
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        //Obtaining the websettings of the webView
        WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();

        //Setting Javascript enabled
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);


                webView.loadUrl("document.getElementById('field_133').value = 'Test';");
                Log.d("onPageFinished", "The Page has finished loading");

            }
        });

        //Obtaining the first item in the cellRef List Array - From here we will access the Url data for the train operator.
        parsedUrl = cellRef.get(0).getUrl();

        //load the page we parsed from online file
        webView.loadUrl(parsedUrl);
        Log.d("loadUrl", "Now load the parsed Url");



    }
```

All I am looking to do at the moment is test that the JS can correctly populate a textbox once the page has loaded with the value of "Test" - However, the WebView appears to be stuck in a loop of loading & refreshing (seeing repeated logcat prints of "The page has finished loading") when trying to run:

`webView.loadUrl("document.getElementById('field_133').value = 'Test';");`

Is this the correct way of trying to inject some JS into the WebView in Android? Apologies if there is something obvious missing, the majority of my experience lies in Swift.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try "javascript:" before the code.
I use this, works perfectly:

```
loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");
```

Comment: This looks to have stopped the 'loop' but now I am shown the page at the correct Url briefly (approx 0.5 seconds), then it shows a white screen with 'Test' in the top left corner of the WebView. Is there a sort of break clause that you need to include in the same way you'd break out of a Switch?